# Minecraft water freezing level

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in a forest hills biome at level 130. I placed water down and nothing is freezing for some reason. I've been AFK for about 30 minutes but still nothing.

Comment: You need to be in a snow\ice biome for water to freeze.

Answer (score 3):

Water only freezes inside a [snowy biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Snowy_biomes). See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ice) for more information.